# Can Someone Explain This?

Tags: insufficient-memory

My storage is being used up and I can't tell what by. Thanks in advance!

[image: Picture]

Comment: I think the rest is what Android uses.

Comment: Please take a look at our [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info). As this is a quite frequent question, we've summed up some first-aid there and linked a couple of "core questions" you could follow up to.

Comment: Assuming you have Android 5.0 or above (based on your UI), at least 2 gb will be used for the Android OS

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your screenshot it is clear that most of your storage is taken up by apps.  Apps have a tendancy to store cached data. If you click on Apps and click individual apps by name you can clear the Cache files which can free up space.

Apps which have a large amount of cache data tends to be web browsers. An example of how much data web browser can store in cache can be seen below.

[image: cache example]

Comment: No, that's not the problem. It says 4.43gb is used up, but only 2.13gb is used by apps so 2.3gb is used by something (I don't know what).

Comment: You seem to have come back with that 'No' awfully fast. Had you already checked the recommended cache review? Or did you have so few apps that it is believable you did so that quickly?

Comment: I don't have many apps, also I have been trying to solve this for a while; I can usually solve problems like this on my own.

Comment: On a more constructive note, here are a couple of our wikis to read on this type of problem; you can get some recommended methods from them: [About internal-storage](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/internal-storage/info), and [About insufficient-memory](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info)

Answer (score 0):

The cached data is your problem. Cached data is in a separate category that is hidden in general. You can clear your cached data by clicking on apps then selecting Google chrome, or something else, then clicking clear cached data. This will not effect your device. After you have done this for about 5 apps, go to the play store and download Norton Clean. This app will clean these caches and any other junk files for you in a millionth of the time.